# Angular JS function not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am learning AngularJS from AngularJS.org video tutorials but when I run my code it says

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ReviewController' is not a function

I got undefined in my console but my code looks the same as in the video here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">
<title>Testing AngularJS</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h3>{{product.name}}
            <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
            <img class="gallery" ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
        </h3>

        <section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(1)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(2)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specifications</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-class="{active: panel.isSelected(3)}"><a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a></li>


            </ul>
            <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
                <h3> Description</h3>

                <h4>{{product.description}}</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
                <h3> Specifications</h3>
                <blockquote>None yet</blockquote>

            </div>
            <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">

                <h3> Reviews</h3>

                <blockquote ng-repeat="review in product.reviews">
                    <b>Stars: {{review.stars}}</b>
                   <p>{{review.body}}</p>
                    <cite>_{{review.author}}</cite>
                </blockquote>
                <form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl">
                    <blockquote>
                        <b>Stars: {{reviewCtrl.review.stars}}</b>
                        <p>{{reviewCtrl.review.body}}</p>
                        <cite>_{{reviewCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                    <label for="select">Select</label>
                    <select id="select" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
                        <option  value="1">1 star</option>
                        <option value="2">2 star</option>
                        <option value="3">3 star</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="comments"></label>
                    <textarea id="comments" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body"></textarea>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>

                    <input ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" type="email" id="email"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

                </form>


            </div>
        </section>

    </li>


</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js file

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        this.products = [
            {
                name: 'Cup',
                price: 2.95,
                description: 'It is the best Buy it fast',

                images: [
                    {
                        full: 'gem.jpeg'
                    }
                ],
                reviews: [
                    {
                        stars: 5,
                        body: 'This is the best gem',
                        author: 'dadsa@dasasd.com'
                    },
                    {
                        stars: 1,
                        body: 'easily broken',
                        author: 'zzzfasdaadsa@dasasd.com'
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                name: 'Bottle',
                price: 1.12,
                description: 'It\'s the best bottle',

                images: [
                    {
                        full: 'gem.jpeg'
                    }
                ],
                reviews: [
                    {
                        stars: 2,
                        body: 'Latest gem',
                        author: 'aasdsa@dasasd.com'
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]; // product is the property of the controller
    });
    app.controller("ReviewController", function () {
        this.review = {};
    });

    app.controller("PanelController", function () {
        this.tab = 1;
        this.selectTab = function (setTab) {
            this.tab = setTab;

        };
        this.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        };
    });


})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Scripts are executed in the order that they are encountered on the page.  So `angular.js` runs before `app.js`.  It will parse the document and try to resolve `ng-app` (and thereby `ng-controller`) before `app.js` has a chance to execute.

There are two easy ways to solve this:

**Put `app.js` inline at the end of your document**

Although I did say that scripts are executed in the order they are encountered, angularjs puts its initialization code behind `document.isready`.  It's loaded, so you will have access to `angular.module`, but it won't execute its bootstrap logic until after your own code has finished loading.  This solution is fine for tiny projects, but isn't great when your code grows large.

**Bootstrap your application manually**

Remove the `ng-app="store"` from your html code, and at the end of `app.js`, you will add the following code

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['store']);
});`
```

If you work with angular long enough, you will get very used to this second solution, as it helps us play nicely with dynamic loaders such as $script,  RequireJS, et al -- not to mention the very example you've posted!